# flask - Server can't start

Tags: python, flask

I am using linux mint mate 17 (base on ubuntu 14.04), I installed flask by"

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install Flask
```

I have python2.7.3 as my default python.

Then write the hello world program hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And try to start the server by `python hello.py`, but it seems didn't start, and there is no any tip, and I can't access localhost:5000, any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to unindent

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```